# How to get nested arrays from json file using json simple

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to get a nested array from a json file, but I can't find a way to do it. What I want is a array with many other arrays. Using  arr.toArray() I get a array with two strings one being "["user1", "name", "password"]" and "["user2", "name", "password"]". Is there a way to get an array with arrays?

```
{
  "Users": {
      "info": [
         ["user1", "name", "password"],
         ["user2", "name", "password"]
       ]
  }

}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("myPath"));

      
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("User1");
            JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) jsonObject1.get("info");
            System.out.println(arr.toArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using GSON or Jackson libraries? Any one of those library will do the work for you!. Just create a POJO and use any of the above library to cast the JSON to a Java object. After casting, you can use the Java object's getters and setters to access the data. Hope this small suggestion may help you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using one of the older JSON Libraries, I believe its the `org.json.simple` library. If this is going to be an important project, I'd recommend switching over to the Google `GSON` Library.

For now, Try Switching

`JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("User1");`

to
`JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("Users");`

this should fix some of your problems. In your JSON file, `Users` is the object you need to get in order to access the `info` Array.

in the mean time, here's a starting place for GSON

##### GSON tutorialspoint

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_quick_guide.htm